# Using matplotlib, how could one compare histograms by overlaying them and by showing their ratio plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Two histograms can be compared by creating a plot that features both an overlay of the histograms (possibly normalised) and a ratio plot of the histograms. Here is such a plot:

[image]

How could a plot like this be made using matplotlib?

Comment: First part is relatively easy. You can draw transparent histograms by setting `alpha` to less than 1 and provide pre-defined bin sizes. Could you explain what exactly the lower plot is supposed to show? You will likely have to do that one manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what the dots are, but here's a simple example of the ratios. The main trick is to reuse the `bin` values that `hist` returns.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal

y = []
y.append(normal(2, 2, size=120))
y.append(normal(2, 2, size=120))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ns, bins, patches = ax1.hist(y, normed=False,
                      histtype='stepfilled',
                      bins=8,
                      alpha=0.2,
                      label=['a','b']
                      )
ax1.legend()

ax2.bar(bins[:-1],     # this is what makes it comparable
        ns[0] / ns[1], # maybe check for div-by-zero!
        alpha=0.4)

ax1.set_ylabel('Data')
ax2.set_ylabel('Ratio (a/b)')
```

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your solution. How could the width of the bins be made consistent? I've noticed that things start to look a bit strange with lower or higher statistics.

(By the way, the dots in my plot are just the ratio values. The shaded area is the statistical uncertainty.)

Comment: "How could the width of the bins be made consistent? " -- you can control the width of the bins in the call to `bar`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

Comment: This still doesn't make the ratio bars start at y=1, how to fix that?

Comment: Could you expand on that, @user7867665? What data should lead to what result?

Comment: @cphlewis in the original question the ratio figure starts at 1 and goes down to 0.5, up to 1.5, whereas in the solution, the bars all start at 0 and go upwards. One solution is to plot `(ratio -1)` and set `bottom=1` in `plt.bar()`. Further to force 1 to be at the centre, the ylim have to be fixed to be equidistant from 1, example `plt.ylim(0,2)`